# Javascript override form onsubmit event not working

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I am overriding a form submit event like this:

```
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
```

But when I call submit on the form like this in a separate function:

```
form.submit();
```

The onsubmit function is not called and the and the form is posted as usual.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

I am also creating a file input in this form and calling its click event immediately. Would this affect the form submit event?:

```
if (fileInput && document.createEvent)
{
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initEvent('click', true, false);
    fileInput.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Edit #2:

I am submitting the form by calling the form's submit function after the file input value has changed:

```
function nameFileLabel(id)
{
    var f = document.getElementById('fileForm' + id);
    var l = document.getElementById("fileText_" + id);
    var i = document.getElementById("fInputId" + id);
    if (i.value != '')
    {
        l.innerHTML = i.value.replace('fakepath', '...');
        var theUploadForm = document.getElementById('fileDiv_' + id);
        theUploadForm.style.visibility = 'visible';
        theUploadForm.style.display = 'block';
        f.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also try onClick="function_name" in your html form tag.

Comment: what i can see now in your edited code that you are posting your form through javascript. And thus the onsubmit is not getting called. Reason is simple, that the browser thinks that you are submitting your form through code so you already have done the preprocessing before calling the submit method.

So, IMO, before you call the f.submit() statement, you should call all other methods you want to perform before submitting the form.

Comment: Manish, see my solution below. You were on the right track. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Manish pointed out, both overriding the submit function and calling the submit form in javascript was complicating how the event was propagating. So added a hidden button in to the form in javascript and called the button's click function instead of the form submit function. WHich seems to have worked even it it feels rather like a kludge! Many thanks for to all of you for your prompt help. :-)

```
function nameFileLabel(id)
{
    var f = document.getElementById('fileForm' + id);
    var l = document.getElementById('fileText_' + id);
    var i = document.getElementById('fInputId' + id);
    var b = document.getElementById('sub' + id);
    if (i.value != '')
    {
        l.innerHTML = i.value.replace('fakepath', '...');
        var theUploadForm = document.getElementById('fileDiv_' + id);
        theUploadForm.style.visibility = 'visible';
        theUploadForm.style.display = 'block';
        b.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To prevent the form posting your function must return false.

```
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This did not work. Also, I added an alert ahead of this which doesn't seem like its called.

Comment: Try replacing form.onsubmit... with document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit..., and add an id="form1" to your form tag in the HTML.

Comment: garryP, I don't think that would work as I am creating the form dynamically in javascript and it would not exist in the DOM at the point I am adding the onsubmit function.

Comment: Can you add the event after the form has been added to the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one

```
form.submit = function() {
  //event.preventDefault();     No need of this call
  //do your processing here
}
```

Comment: The brace is not the issue, it was simply ommitted by the user asking this question.

Comment: I changed the name of the function though.

Comment: I did not see that change. It would have been better to note this in your comment what you actually changed that you think solves the issue. However .submit is not the event attached to the form, as described at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: Well, if you see the question, Xavi wrote
form.onsubmit
and I make the change as 
form.submit

Comment: Manish I changed the function to submit which stopped the post, but then i get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: The reason is that you override the submit method (native method) of the form's. And thus the default event object parameter is not able to retrieve. You can simply remove that statement if you want to go ahead, but i don't think so its an optimum solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following @garryp's answer on "return false". Further reading from MDN [event.stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) to see some use cases and differences between event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation.

On the side note, "return false;" is the same as calling both;

```
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: stopPropagation is also not working. I do not think the function is being called whatsoever.

Comment: hmm, try using a breakpoint on browser dev tools ie. firebug or chrome. I will also try adding "console.log('submited');" + other watch variables. Lastly, understanding the concept of events and how it bubbles up. Basically, preventDefault() stops the default action from being triggered, stopPropagation will not allow it from bubbling up the DOM, but others within scope will be trigger. Lastly, stopImmediatePropogation.. stops it all.