# Html form submitting modifying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have two input buttons on my page.

The first one is a hidden input that passes value from php code to the other visible input.

The second buttton is a visible submit button that gets value from the hidden button in order for it to process correctly.

I am trying to submit the hidden button. When the visible button is clicked, it submits the hidden button. Before that, the other button gets a value and passes it to the visible one. Here are the two submit buttons:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="cart" id="cart" value="<? php  echo $Product ?> ">
 <input type="submit" name="cart1" id="add to cart" value="1">
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.you just need to put your two inputs into a form and when you submit you can get value from $_POST['cart']

Comment: Did you warp your html with <form> tag, please show complete code.

Comment: You need to override the submit event. Go look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966619/javascript-override-form-onsubmit-event-not-working) and if you still have trouble - update your question!

Comment: Break your 3 line long word hell into 2-3 sentences. You can't await from other to decipher multiline crap.

Comment: @peterh why are you angry?

Comment: Because I started to *decode* your 3-line long sentence, I even dismantled the first sub-sentence from this chaos, but finally I decided you don't deserve it. Because I think you *could* produce a comprehensible text, but you simply don't bother. So I think a "very low quality" flag was a better option. It will likely result the closure of your question.

Comment: Finally I became so angry that I fixed your sentence. This part: *"so that when clicking the visible button"* was unneeded. Likely you started to type in something, *then you changed your mind inside the sentence*, and continued to write a different sentence. Actually, 2-3 different one. Without a single punctuation, point, anything. I think it is really not a wonder why are you anonym - also I wouldn't be pride to post similar "content" to the Internet.

Comment: @peterh  hey there is no need for that you can just ignore  the entire post. I don't need your help.

Comment: @peterh  There are many people who are willing to help in a nice way. If there is something you don't like in the question you can say it in a nice way and I will be more than happy to change it other than that you can just ignore it. As I said, I'm not forcing you to help me.

Answer (score -1):

think this is what what you are trying do

```
$('input[name="cart1"]').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
hidden_input= $('input[name="cart"]').val()
$(this).val(hidden_input)
// then you can consider sending your form data via ajax
// ensure the inputs are wrapped within a <form> tag like 
luo said
data = $(this).parents('form').serialize()

$.ajax({
    type: 'post', 
    data: formdata, 
    ....}) // ajaxx  here


})
```